# How do I give a Sublime Text 3 plugin precedence in the gutter?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have [BraketHighlighter](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/BracketHighlighter) and [GitGutter](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/GitGutter) installed in Sublime Text 3.

Both plugins add icons to the gutter. Notice that the GitGutter icon (the purple dot) supercedes the BracketHighlighter icon (where the left curly brace should be):

http://i5.minus.com/jb0iAzbxK8v9Kv.png

**How do I make BracketHighlighter supercede GitGutter?**

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be a common issue! [Another example](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-for-ST2/issues/554)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a separate keymap with a higher order of precedence. [Source](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility/packages.html#merging-and-order-of-precedenceYou).

Comment: The problem seems to have gone away on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the section on [protected regions](https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter#protected-regions)

From the [README](https://github.com/jisaacks/GitGutter/blob/1f673cbe009e2e0f4393c25e83be895871b4923f/README.md):

#### Protected Regions

Is GitGutter blocking SublimeLinter or other icons? You can prevent this by adding which regions you would like GitGutter to not override:

```
"protected_regions": ["region", "names"]
```

You will need to figure out the names of the regions you are trying to protect.

---

Take a look at the later comments in this issue of if you are unsure how to

> figure out the names of the regions you are trying to protect.